# How to identify abbreviations/acronyms and expand them in spaCy?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have a large (~50k) term list and a number of these key phrases / terms have corresponding acronyms / abbreviations. I need a fast way of finding either the abbreviation or the expanded abbreviation ( i.e. MS -> Microsoft ) and then replacing that with the full expanded abbreviation + abbreviation ( i.e. Microsoft -> Microsoft (MS) or MS -> Microsoft (MS) ).

I am very new to spaCy, so my naive approach was going to be to use [spacy_lookup](https://spacy.io/universe/?id=spacy-lookup) and use both the abbreviation and the expanded abbreviation as keywords and then using some kind of [pipeline extension](https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-v2-pipelines-extensions) to then go through the matches and replace them with the full expanded abbreviation + abbreviation.

Is there a better way of tagging and resolving acronyms/abbreviations in spaCy?

Comment: Also [posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacynlp/comments/9jysst/spacy_abbreviationacronym_handling/).

Answer (score 14):

Check out [scispacy](https://github.com/allenai/scispacy#abbreviationdetector) on GitHub, which implements the acronym identification heuristic described in [this paper](https://psb.stanford.edu/psb-online/proceedings/psb03/schwartz.pdf), (see also [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_HSKDALwuw&t=11m41s)). The heuristic works if acronyms are "introduced" in the text with a pattern like

> StackOverflow (SO) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. SO rocks!

A working way to replace all acronyms in a piece of text with their long form could then be

```
import spacy
from scispacy.abbreviation import AbbreviationDetector

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

abbreviation_pipe = AbbreviationDetector(nlp)
nlp.add_pipe(abbreviation_pipe)

text = "StackOverflow (SO) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. SO rocks!"

def replace_acronyms(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    altered_tok = [tok.text for tok in doc]
    for abrv in doc._.abbreviations:
        altered_tok[abrv.start] = str(abrv._.long_form)

    return(" ".join(altered_tok))

replace_acronyms(text)
```

Comment: This is great.. But all scispacy items are on biomedical. Is such abbreviater available for other domains too?

Comment: @SandeepBhutani the heuristic used by scispacy will work OK if acronyms are introduced in the way I described in the answer (regardless the domain!). scispacy is borrowing a language model to do the tokenization (in my answer, `en_core_web_en`), so it shouldn't skew "biomedical" in its behavior. I guess that (as per usual), one has to try and measure precision/recall on acronym replacement to see if a recipe like this works on a corpus of choice.

Comment: Thanks. Got it after running .. abbr should be defined already in setence, is case sensitive, should have same letters as of expansion etc.. so it is essentially rule based detection. Kind of utility . But helpful