# spaCy: Scispacy abbreviation large document

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, chunking

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570805/how-to-identify-abbreviations-acronyms-and-expand-them-in-spacy) looking for a way to identify and clean abbreviations within my dataframe. The code works well for my use case.

However, I'm dealing with a large data set and was wondering if there was a better or proficient way to apply this without dealing with memory issues.

In order for me to run the code snipet, I sampled 10% of the original dataset and it runs perfectly. If I run the full dataset, my laptop locks.

Below is updated version of the original code:

```
import spacy
from scispacy.abbreviation import AbbreviationDetector

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.max_length = 43793966

abbreviation_pipe = AbbreviationDetector(nlp)
nlp.add_pipe(abbreviation_pipe)

text = [nlp(text, disable = ['ner', 'parser','tagger']) for text in train.text]

text = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in text]) 


doc = nlp(text)

#Print the Abbreviation and it's definition
print("Abbreviation", "\t", "Definition")
for abrv in doc._.abbreviations:
    print(f"{abrv} \t ({abrv.start}, {abrv.end}) {abrv._.long_form}")
```