# How to identify the first occurrence of an Acronym in documents

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, spacy

I have a few documents wherein there is a scope of various acronyms being used. I need to find out if they have already defined the Acronyms for the first time before using them again in the document. For instance:

> The purpose of this paper is to provide Global Banking and Markets(GBM) and Risk Management Meeting(RMM) with a better understanding of the frameworks.
> The purpose of this is to present the annual review of the RMM’s Terms of Reference. The proposed ToR is provided in the Appendix. The purpose of this paper is to outline the GBM Risk Management Meeting’s (GBM RMM) role and responsibilities for TOR used in GBM and the resulting model risk.

Here they have defined the Acronyms before using them except for TOR. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify Abbreviations/Acronyms and expand them in spaCy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570805/how-to-identify-abbreviations-acronyms-and-expand-them-in-spacy)

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov That solution was for replacing all the abbrevations if it was initially explained but mine is slightly different.